# Characters in Mac OS X Terminal misaligned when accents are involved

Tags: macos, sqlite, terminal, character

I was working in the terminal with SQLite's `sqlite3` command-line shell and I retrieved a list of stuff.
As you can see, the *LastName*s and the *Country*s are **not** lined up to the first dash under their corresponding column, but they should be.
[image: Imperfect Alignment]

If you've noticed, this only happens when there are accented characters in the row. This does not happen on Windows.

Is there some setting for the terminal to fix this? I am using Homebrew style.

Here were the commands, not that I think they matter:

.header on

.mode column

.width 20 20 15

SELECT FirstName, LastName, Country FROM Customer;

Comment: what sqlite3 cli command did you use?

Comment: I've edited my post. I doubt that they're of any use, because  this is something that works on Windows, and not Mac.

Comment: For instance, the output is UTF-8 and the program displaying it does not account for the number of bytes per character.  It could be a problem with locales -- but as the first question suggests, the starting point would be to identify the program in question.

Comment: It seems to be assuming that 16-bit characters take 2 character spaces on the output line. Could it possibly be something to do with your font? Have you tried changing that? Maybe you can have sqlite output to a file and run the file through `xxd` or somesuch to see actually how many spaces/characters there really are.

Comment: I'll try a Unicode 16bit, I suppose.